# Outline Tag support in jxls 2.x

Tags: jxls

I am migrating from jxls 1.0 to jxls 2.x.

We have used outline tag for for rows as below in our templates.

```
<jx:outline detail=true>
      //Some rows
</jx:outline>
```

It basically shows groupBy outline option present in excel Data tab. 
I want to replicate this as it is. I could not find similar tag in jxls 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jxls-demo repo, there is an example of Group row command which worked.

Thank you @leonid-vysochyn for this suggestion.

Check the following classes:
[GroupRowCommand.java](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/ce987cba7b87afbcf4a12bddd428b05b27006209/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/GroupRowCommand.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[UserCommandExcelMarkupDemo.java](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/ce987cba7b87afbcf4a12bddd428b05b27006209/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/UserCommandExcelMarkupDemo.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)